# Dynamically change YouTube 'controls' playervars

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am working on a player that on load will seek to a specified time and start looping a short section of the video. This will be used as a background at first, however, there is an overlay with a styled play button that will provide video details. Upon clicking the button the video will reset to start, unmute, and play. I have everything working except that when the video resets it breaks the onPlayerStateChange event, meaning the video will not detect ended and reset it's loop. I believe it comes down to how I am changing the playerVars, by accessing the src attribute and changing 'controls=0' to 'controls=1'. Is there a more correct way to change these attributes that will not break the player events? I have a fiddle set up here: https://jsfiddle.net/BearSkull/uqje4793/

```
  //This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

//This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//after the API code downloads.
var youTubeId = '-hTVNidxg2s';
var startTime = 85; //start time in seconds
var stopTime = 95; //end time in seconds
var playInterval = (stopTime - startTime) * 1000; //converts to milliseconds
var ratio = 16 / 9; //YT player ratio
var playerWidth = jQuery(window).width();
var playerHeight = Math.ceil(playerWidth / ratio);
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
  height: playerHeight,
  width: playerWidth,
  videoId: youTubeId,
  playerVars: {
    'controls': 0,
    'showinfo': 0
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

var intervalCallbackId

var loopFunction = function() {
  intervalCallbackId = setInterval(playerSeek, playInterval);
};

function playerSeek() {
  player.seekTo(startTime);
};

//The API will call this function when the video player is ready.

var started = false;

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  jQuery('.hero-background-image').delay(1500).fadeOut(1000);
  if (started === false) {
    player.seekTo(startTime).mute().playVideo();
    loopFunction(event);
    started = true;
  } else {
    player.seekTo(0).unMute().setVolume(100).playVideo();
  }
}

//Play Button Click Function

jQuery(".desktop-play-btn").on('click', function() {
  var src = jQuery('#youtube-player').attr('src');
  jQuery('#youtube-player').attr('src', src.replace("controls=0", "controls=1"));
  clearInterval(intervalCallbackId);
  jQuery('#player-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
  jQuery('#hero-youtube-video, #youtube-player').css({
    'z-index': '99'
  });
  player.seekTo(0).unMute().setVolume(100).playVideo();
});

//The API calls this function when the player's state changes.

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.seekTo(startTime).mute().playVideo();
    loopFunction(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to achieve this? Please let me know, i am also looking for the same...

Comment: Same here. Any update?